# ¿Cómo usar dos fuentes de letras en tcpdf en la misma linea?

Tags: php, table, tcpdf

Tengo que usar dos fuentes de letra con la librería de tcpdf, pero no me es posible, como le aplico al texto diferentes fonts sin crear otro multicell

```
$pdf->setFont("montserratlight",'',7);//para el titulo
$pdf->setFont("montserratmedium",'',7);//para el el contenido
$pdf->MultiCell(20,20,"este es el titulo \n y este el contenido","C");
```

También pensé en crear una función para usarla cuando necesite, pero no funciono

```
function foo($pdf, $arg_1)
{
  $pdf->SetFont('montserratmedium', '', 10);
  $valor = $pdf->Text('','', 'qwerty');
  return $valor;
}
$textoPrueba = '<tr>
                   <td>texto normal ' . (foo($pdf, 'textoMedium')) . ' texto normal</td>
                </tr>';
<tbody>
    ' . $textoPrueba . '
</tbody>
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda, Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para utilizar dos fuentes de letras en la misma lineas puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$pdf->SetFont("montserratlight", '', 7); // Establecer la primera fuente
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, "Este es el ", 0, 0, 'L'); // Imprimir parte del texto con la primera fuente

$pdf->SetFont("montserratmedium", '', 7); // Establecer la segunda fuente
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, "título", 0, 0, 'L'); // Imprimir parte del texto con la segunda fuente

$pdf->SetFont("montserratmedium", '', 7); // Establecer nuevamente la segunda fuente
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, " y este es el ", 0, 0, 'L'); // Imprimir otra parte del texto con la segunda fuente

$pdf->SetFont("montserratlight", '', 7); // Establecer nuevamente la primera fuente
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, "contenido", 0, 1, 'L'); // Imprimir la última parte del texto con la primera fuente y saltar de línea
```

En este ejemplo, se utilizan las funciones [SetFont()](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rfpdf/1.17.4/TCPDF:SetFont) y [Cell()](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rfpdf/1.17.4/TCPDF:Cell) en lugar de `MultiCell()`.

El último parámetro de la función `Cell()` se establece en 'L' para alinear el texto a la izquierda. Puedes ajustar los parámetros según tus necesidades.

Ten en cuenta que la función `SetFont()` debe llamarse antes de cada parte del texto que desees imprimir con una fuente diferente, de lo contrario no va a funcionar.